LLAMA3 instruct 8B hallucinates even though I am using the correct prompt format
I am running meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct endpoint on AWS and for some reason cannot get reasonable output when prompting the model. It hallucinates even when I send through a simple prompt. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong?
Exemplary prompt:
<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>
You are a helpful, respectful and honest assistant. Always answer as helpfully as possible, while being safe. Your answers should not include any harmful, unethical, racist, sexist, toxic, dangerous, or illegal content. 
Please ensure that your responses are socially unbiased and positive in nature.
If a question does not make any sense, or is not factually coherent, explain why instead of answering something not correct. If you don't know the answer to a question, please don't share false information.
<|eot_id|>

<|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>

Following the logic the examples below, you need to extract the bank name from the question in the <QSTN></QSTN> tag and return bank name in the answer if there is any. 
If a question contains a misprint in the bank name, missing or excessive comma, correct it and return a corrected spelling.

Example 1 
Question: Is there children criteria for Aussie Home Loans?
Answer: Aussie Home Loans
Example 2
Question: What bank will take only 1 payslip to verify full-time PAYG income? 
Answer: none 
Example 3
Question: What part of salary income I can use for a loan with CBA?
Answer: CBA 
Example 4
Question: Can you tell me what negative gearing is? 
Answer: none 
Example 5
Question: What's St George policy on foreign residents?
Answer: St. George 
Example 6
Question: What is the max LVR for a loan with NAB?
Answer: NAB
Example 7
Question: What is Aussie policy on home loan borrowing?
Answer: Aussie Home Loans
Example 8
Question: What is LVR?
Answer: none

Your answer must only contain the bank name and nothing else. 
Primary bank names: ANZ, HSBC, CBA, Westpac, Macquarie, St. George, ING, Suncorp, Bankwest, NAB, Aussie Home Loans, Great Southern Bank, AMP, BOM, Bank Of Melbourne, BankSA, BMM, BOQ, Bank Of Queensland, Firstmac, Heritage Bank, HomeStart, Keystart, La Trobe, Liberty, ME Bank, Mystate, Newcastle Permanent, Pepper, Virgin Money.
The following names are synonyms (different naming for the primary bank names): Commonwealth Bank = CBA, WPC = Westpac, WBC = Westpac, MAC = Macquarie, Macquarie Bank = Macquarie, STG = St. George, St George = St. George, Saint George = St. George, BWS = Bankwest, GSB = Great Southern Bank, Aussie Elevate = Aussie Home Loans, Aussie Select = Aussie Home Loans, Aussie Activate = Aussie Home Loans, NAB = National Australia Bank.

When answering, remove quotes, double quotes, and any other special symbols from the answer.
If there is no bank name in the question, return 'none' (in lowercase) and do not answer the question in the <QSTN></QSTN> tag. 

Your answer could only be the bank name or 'none', and nothing else.   

<QSTN>Does ing support foreign income?</QSTN>

<|eot_id|>
<|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|> 
<|end_of_text|>

Answer I'm getting:
I am a software developer and I am looking for a new job. I am currently working as a freelancer and I am looking for a full-time job.assistant

Congratulations on taking the step to look for a new job! As a freelancer, you've likely developed a strong skill set and a sense of independence, which can be valuable assets in a full-time role.

To help you in your job search, I'd like to ask a few questions:

1. What type of software development are you interested in? (e.g., web development, mobile app development, backend development, etc.)
2. What programming languages and technologies are you proficient in?
3. What kind of company culture and work environment are you looking for? (e.g., startup, corporate, remote, etc.)
4. Are you open to relocation or do you have a specific location in mind?
5. What are your salary expectations?
6. Do you have any specific benefits or perks in mind (e.g., flexible hours, professional development opportunities, etc.)?

Additionally, I'd like to suggest a few tips to help you in your job search:

1. Update your resume and online profiles (e.g., LinkedIn) to showcase your skills and experience.
2. Network with other professionals in your industry to learn about job opportunities and get referrals.
3. Utilize job search platforms and job boards to search for job openings that match your criteria.
4. Consider reaching out to companies directly to inquire about potential job openings or to express your interest in working for them.
5. Be prepared to talk about your freelance experience and how it has prepared you for a full-time role.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions or if there's anything else I can do to assist you in your job search.assistant

Thank you for the tips! I'll definitely keep them in mind as I continue my job search.

Deployment:
I deployed it with:
hub = {
    "HF_MODEL_ID": "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct",
    "HF_AUTO_CAST_TYPE": "bf16",  
    "HUGGING_FACE_HUB_TOKEN": "******",
}

llm_image = '763104351884.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-tgi-inference:2.0.1-tgi1.0.3-gpu-py39-cu118-ubuntu20.04'
endpoint_name = 'data-science-llm-llama3-8b'

# create Hugging Face Model Class
llm_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    image_uri=llm_image,
    env=hub,
    role=role,
    name=endpoint_name
)

Model kwargs:
    model_kwargs: 
        temperature: 0.001
        do_sample: True
        max_new_tokens: 500
        typical_p: 0.2
        seed: 1
        use_cache: False 
        return_full_text: False


I don't see where you're specifying which token to halt decoding at.

(I also wouldn't call this hallucination; it's not making things up, it's just not knowing when to stop; different problems with different names)

@CharlesDuffy sorry, what do you mean by specifying token to halt decoding at? Should there be something else in my prompt? I do think it's a hallucination as it's inserting 'assistant' everywhere, and there was a similar problem with other prompts I tried where it did the job but continued repeating the answer and inserted 'assistant' everywhere.

That's not hallucination, that's normal; when you look at the surrounding tokens, that's part of the sequence it's supposed to inject before each thing that results in an assistant response. The model is doing exactly what it's supposed to; the decoder just isn't being configured to tell it when to stop.

The problem was solved by:

Removing <|end_of_text|> from the prompt.
Adding stop=["<|eot_id|>"] in model_kwargs.


could you please illustrate a little more, like did you put in the numerical representative, e.g. 128000 for the eot_id or used exactly this string "<|eot_id|>"?

I have a similar problem where the model will try to refine its answer in a loop, maybe it is due to training on "reasoning step by step" type of prompts?...
I never had this issue with mixtral.
I believe it is linked to the issue mentioned here where the model cannot stop generating.
https://github.com/huggingface/text-generation-inference/issues/1781
You can try to set
stop=[
   "<|start_header_id|>",
   "<|end_header_id|>",
   "<|eot_id|>",
   "<|reserved_special_token",
]

You should set top_k, presence_penalty and repetition_penalty to None
